# Dubgger for Chrome in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a JavaScript program on chrome, but it does not work.

Details:

- OS: Windows 10.
- IDE: Visual Studio Code.
- Debugger configuration (json):

  ```
  {

  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

  {

      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
    {
      "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9222,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, here are the details.
I had to reconfigure the JASON file as follows:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [{
        "name": "Launch Client Side",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "file": "${workspaceRoot}/file_name.html",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch Server Side",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost/mypage.html",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "wwwroot"
    }

]
```

}

Note: In order to use the debug features of Visual Studio Code, you need to refresh the browser after you launched the HTML file.